# Comma separated number with zero append using angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to enter a number in input element with comma separated and once user hit tab or click outside the input element need to append zero.
Below are the scenario:

```
1] 123456789.12345678 -> 123,456,789.12345678
2] 123456789.1234     -> 123,456,789.12340000
3] 123456.1234        -> 123,456.12340000
```

Comment: This is the wrong to add 0 before decimal and after some value. 123456.1234        -> 123,456,000.12340000 this is wrong.

Comment: @surendrakumar i have modified my question...

Answer (score 0):

Use the **number** pipe here for the correct scenario.

e.g.  `{{123456789.1234 | number: 9.8-8}}`

```
output: 123,456,789.12340000
```

See the link[pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: I am aware about this but i need to do on this input element when user typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")` after converting your number to string with `toString()`. I have used it yesterday referenced from one of the SO's old post. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) . This is what you are looking for I guess.

Or you can check the angular built in `number` pipe for that matter.